# Handling Splits In Java Blackjack Simulator - Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I am creating a blackjack simulator to teach myself java and it has already been very helpful.  This is the last piece and then it will be functional.  I am having trouble with handling splits.  If you don't play blackjack, a split means that the player has the opportunity to take each card of their initial hand and create a new hand for each.

Currently, there is a card class, and a deck which is an arraylist of cards.  There is also a player class which has an object called hand, also an arraylist of cards. The player has a variable called bet which is the amount to wager on each hand.

The issue with a split is that it creates an additional hand and now each of these hands has its own bet.  Do I need to revamp the program and make hand its own class?  That seems like overkill and it may very well create problems of its own. For instance, at some point, the player is going to have to handle multiple hands anyway.

The second thought I have is to handle it all within the play method, which handles all basic strategy, recursively.  There are two problems, one, I have never used recursion, and two, there is still the fact that there is only one hand object per person.

The third idea, which also seems messy, is to crate a playerSplit class that extends the person class and creates an additional hand.  The issue is that there may be multiple splits per person in any given round.

I am including the code I believe is relevant since the program is a bit long to include it all.  Please let me know if there is additional code needed.

Human constructor

```
public Human(String name, Deck deck){
    this.handValue = 0;
    this.name = name;
    this.hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    this.deck = deck;
}
```

Player constructor (Player class extends Human):

```
public Player(String name, Deck deck, double minBet, double maxBet){
    super(name, deck);
    this.bankroll = 1000;
    this.minBet = minBet;
    this.maxBet = maxBet;
    this.bet = minBet;
}
```

Comment: Why not make the Player capable of holding more than one Hand instance?

Comment: That certainly gets to the heart of it.  How can that be done when I don't know how many hands might ultimately be held?  This assumes that  there is no limit on number of times a hand can be split.

Comment: Use some type of collection (List, Set, etc).

Comment: Just make an `List<Hand>` or `List<List<Card>>` to hold multiple hands. `Set` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Try think about how the different objects interact in a game of blackjack. A dealer deals cards to players, who then have a hand, or hands if the hand has been split.

In your `Human` constructor, you have an arraylist of cards representing the hand. Instead of tying this in to the human, you should instead have a separate class for a hand of cards.

Let the `Hand` class have the list of cards, the bet associated with it, and the rest of the methods which are relevant to the hand.

In the `Human` class, have an arraylist which stores all the player's hands, something like this:

```
ArrayList<Hand> hands;
```

Also have a method which can split a hand which takes a hand as an input and returns the new hands after the split. You could do it something like this:

```
public ArrayList<Hand> splitHand(Hand h)
```

When programming applications like this, you should separate everything into their own class which can act independently from each other, encapsulating their logic. Instead of your hand being attached directly to the player as group of cards, you should recognize that a hand of cards is an independent object with its own properties and methods. It is a lot easier to program in this manner. For example, checking whether or not a hand equals 21 can be done by adding a method onto the hand class which is called like `hand.getSum()` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion seems inappropriate for representing the state of the system.

Assuming a player has multiple hands, each hand has it's own state and has to be rendered in the gui, you are better off having a one-to-many relationship between each player and the number of hands being played.

In blackjack, a player can also sit down at a table and play multiple hands on the table, so this one-to-many relationship already exists if you are going to simulate actual casino-style play.